# Pictures compiling into wrong sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, xcode6

I've created a game using `SpriteKit` in Xcode 5. Everything worked perfectly, I tested the app on all of the iPhones in Xcode 5 and the game worked beautifully; however, I was planning to release it sometime this week and updated to Xcode 6 so I can see if the app would work on the iPhone 6 (I saw no reason why It wouldn't, but I wanted to try on the simulator).

I am not sure where to start to look for bugs, since everything worked exactly the way I wanted it to, so I'm sorry if I cannot provide you with any information about what I've tried so far. On a side note, the resizing is only weird in simulator, when I compile the same code in Xcode 6 on my actual device, it still works fine.

I have heard that the iPhone 6 automatically resized things, but is this the case?

Is it a problem with the simulator? Xcode 6? Should I release the app and don't worry?

```
node1     = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redUp"]]];
node2     = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redUp"]]];
```

The above code is an example of two of the images that are being scaled wrong on simulator on device. After the above lines, all I do is add a couple actions and set properties such as name and physics body.

http://postimg.org/image/j2hbw2of9/
This link shows the simulator running the game. This is NOT what is supposed to happen.

http://postimg.org/image/fe3asuaav/ 
This IS what's supposed to happen. This is a screenshot of my iPhone running the game, NOT the simulator. Perhaps this is because simulator is iOS8 and my iPhone is iOS 7? Why would that make a difference?

**EDIT** The reason my device works but not simulator (I believe) is because I don't have iOS 8 on my device yet. Could that be a reason?

Comment: If you want, but can't, post pictures, post the link, and if a user with higher rep find the images usefull, they will include them

Comment: Do you mean iPhone 6 or 6 Plus? They are very different.

Comment: Could you show the code that you're using to size or obtain the images?

Comment: You're not using `nativeScale` and `nativeBounds`, are you? If so, that's the source of the issue; they are different for simulator vs. device.

Comment: Every single device is scaling images very wrong. Simulator for iPhone 5, 5s, 4, 4s, 6, and 6 plus; EVEN THOUGH when I test on an actual iPhone 5, everything works fine. See above post for the code I use; and I am not sure what nativeScale and nativeBounds are, I shall look them up right now.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you use `textureWithImageNamed:`?

Comment: My gameScene is very lengthy (more than 2K lines of code) and contains various images, which I have tried calling with various methods. I have images in xcassets, in .atlases, and even in supporting files. Nothing works.

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong. You need to provide a picture of what is wrong in the simulator and a picture of what you would expect.

Comment: Pictures have been added

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. For those in the future with the same problem, my @2x image was not scaled down in iOS 7, and so in iOS8 I added an  `NSLog` statement to output the size of my images. For some reason they were twice as small. I went into Inkscape and doubled the sizes for every picture, thus solving the issue.